# PHPStorm type hinting from array key

Tags: arrays, phpstorm, type-hinting

Is it possible to typehint based on an array key in PHPStorm?  For example, say I have an array:

```
$a = array('\Fully\Namespaced\ClassName' => $objectInstance);
```

Can I have PHPStorm infer that `$a['\Fully\Namespaced\ClassName']` is an instance of `\Fully\Namespaced\ClassName`?

I know the preferred method would be to have the function creating `$objectInstance` specify its return type, but my particular setup (out of my control) precludes me from doing so.

Comment: It depends on actual array (how you create/use it). But in general: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the reply!  This looks promising, but I'm running into trouble.  This is representative of my setup: [http://pastie.org/10420353](http://pastie.org/10420353).  Slim\Container is a class which implements ArrayAccess, so I believe your solution is applicable, but $foo is being hinted as Slim\Container, not Foo.  Any ideas?

Comment: I do not know what to say -- it definitely worked in the past ([original ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17116)). I may suggest asking there and/or filing new ticket to their Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI . Access via factory method still runs fine. Maybe it conflicts with one of the 3rd party (custom) plugins you may have there?

Comment: I opened a new ticket with JetBrains ([https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28898](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28898)). I'll update here as progress is made.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** @var $objectInstance \Fully\Namespaced\ClassName */
```

Add it before array declaration.